# When does Redux Store updates the props of a subscribed component-- Is it asynchronous event?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to get my head around a scenario where I am dispatching a synchronous redux action (using `createAction` of `typesafe-actions`) and soon after that making a network call that relies on updated props from the store.

***Scenario:***

Inside clearFilters handler function (handler function invoked on click of clear filters button), I am dispatching a synchronous action and then making a network call as below:

```
clearFilters = (): void => {
    this.props.resetFilters(); //action dispatched
    this.refreshData;   //network call
};
```

Inside the `refreshData` function, my component expects updated filter props and based on it, it creates a searchCondition to be passed to the list api call as payload.

```
refreshData = (): void => {
    const { listData, filters } = this.props; //get the filters prop

    //Expected filters to be updated from the store post dispatch of action
    const SearchCondition: SearchCondition = createSearchConditions(filters);
    
    listData({
        SearchCondition,
        MaxResults: this.maxRecordsCount,
        SortFields: this.getSortFields(),
    }),
 );
};
```

My component is subscribed to the `filters` prop using `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
   filters: state.common.filter.filters,
});
```

Given that is the state of the problem I am facing, I tried to debug what happens by placing debug points in the code:

1. When the action is dispatched (inside `clearFilters` function)
2. Inside the reducer, where updated state is returned.
3. When the network call is invoked (inside `clearFilters` function)
4. In the `refreshData` call.

After reducer returns updated state, as per the debugging knowledge, store did not send the updated props right away. Rather, the control goes back to the next line i.e. `this.refreshData()` which make network call with old filters data. Only after the `clearFilters` function call finishes, in my `componentDidUpdate`, i can see that props update happen.

Does that signifies redux state change back to the store and eventually subscribed prop updates happen in an ASYNC way? If so, how does it happen? Does store sending the updated props executes in the main thread?

Any pointers/documentation would be really helpful.

Comment: Maybe this could help you -> https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/fe0ace21910bc596cd8f3ec8ccc78bccdae7d426/src/createStore.js#L158-L216 As you can see dispatching action is synchronous but  the changes are not reflected in the same React cycle, the updates go through a re-render state and it call the update lifecycle method (or useEffect hook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispatch is synchronous, and the *queueing* of the React updates is synchronous.  However, React will not re-render that component until after this whole event processing is completed, and `this.props` will *not* be updated until after that render happens.  So, no, you cannot access `this.props` right after dispatching an action and expect that it has been updated.  That will never be true.

I would suggest reading these posts that go into extensive detail on both React and React-Redux:

- [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/)
- [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/)

Comment: Thank you Mark! One last question: Would taking api call off the main thread by doing something like `setTimeout(this.refreshData)` is right way to wait for the props updates or should I invoke api call in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method?

Comment: I would put it in the lifecycle methods. (Or even better, rewrite this as a function component and use the `useEffect` hook.)